# Global Validation with standard form submit in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In asp.net core i am doing global validation by adding global `ActionFilterAttribute`

```
public class ValidateRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);                
        }
    }
}
```

and then register it in startup

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateRequestAttribute));
})
```

I have simple model with server side validation and corresponding form

```
public class TaskModel: IValidatableObject
{
    public int? TaskID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Task Name is required.")]
    public string TaskName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Do server side validation
        if (TaskName != "MyTask")
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Server validation failed.", new string[] { nameof(TaskName) });
        }
        else
        {
            yield return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
<button form="createForm" type="submit" id="btnSave">Save</button>

<form id="createForm" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Tasks">    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="TaskName">Task Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control w-25" asp-for="TaskName" />
        <span asp-validation-for="TaskName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I also have `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` included.

When i click on submit without entering Task Name, the client side validaiton works as expected and shows error message on the UI.
[image]

When server validation fails, and since i have global validation enabled,  server returns 400 with serialized model state as expected.
However, UI renders string message `{"TaskName":["Server validation failed."]}`

[image]

I understand why this is happening, but of-course that is not expected behavior.

Is there any better way to handle validation globally in standard form submit scenario?

or we should i only stick to Ajax POST if i am doing global validation.

Comment: `context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);` sets the result to a 400 error page with the model state, which will send the ModelState in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in one of the SO post,

```
public class ValidateRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ValidateRequestAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Controller controller = context.Controller as Controller;
            object model = context.ActionArguments.Any()
               ? context.ActionArguments.First().Value
               : null;

            context.Result = (IActionResult)controller?.View(model)
               ?? new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);          
    }
}
```